# How to share keychain data between a WatchKit extension and an iPhone app

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am unable to share data between WatchKit and an iPhone app using a shared keychain. When I am trying to use `kSecAttrAccessible` as `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways` in keychain wrapper, `SecItemUpdate` failed. Please help me to use `kSecAttrAccessible` in keychain wrapper properly.

Comment: did you turn on keychain sharing as described in the documentation?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html

Comment: Yes i have already turned on the keychain but problem is happening kSecAttrAccessible value is by default set as  kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked  so when iphone is locked value is not available in apple watch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the correct accessibility mode:

The default keychain modes `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked` and `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly` will not let your app extension access data while the iPhone is locked.

Therefore, use `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` or `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` are appropriate in this case. This allows the WatchKit extension to access the keychain even when the iOS app is in the background.

Old items (with `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked`) have to be re-saved (read, delete, save with new accessibility mode).

More information (including code) is available [here](http://whitesky.io/sharing-app-data-between-ios-apps-and-watchkit-extensions/), [here](https://www.secsign.com/tag/secure-cloud-sharing/), and [here](https://realm.io/news/architecting-app-apple-watch-natashatherobot/).

Comment: Thanks Vomako .Could you please let me know how we can read delete save with new accessibility mode in Keychain wrapper (objective c) as i tried deleting and saving new one but not able to do that and getting -50 error.I have already tried and debugged the issue for 2-3 days but unable to make it work with apple watch.

Comment: Vomako i checked through the code but still getting issue .Could you please let me know how i can changed the keychainitemwrapper apple class for kSecAttrAccessible.

Comment: Tried plenty of time but unable to share data between watch app and iphone when phone is locked .Can someone please help that how to edit keychainitemwrapper apple class to support data sharing kSecAttrAccessibleAlways